# If and statement equating to True, but should be False

Tags: python, django

So I have the following code:

```
if old_size < new_size and date_exceeded and usage(user) < new_size:
    unset_date_exceeded()
```

The problem is this is evaluating to True even when the values suggest otherwise:

```
logger.info('oS:%s | nS:%s | dE:%s | usage:%s' % (old_size, new_size, date_exceeded, usage(user)))
# returns oS:262144000 | nS:536870912 | dE:2013-04-22 10:27:08+00:00 | usage:908811325
```

Notice that usage(user) < new_size should be `False` but for some reason it's not working out that way.

I thought maybe I didn't understand how `and` functions, but if I try this in a python shell I can't replicate it and instead get the expected result:

```
>>> oS=         262144000
>>> nS=         536870912
>>> usage=       908811325
>>> dE="2013-04-22 10:27:08+00:00"
>>> oS < nS and dE and usage < nS
False
```

I'm fairly certain I'm losing my mind and missing a typo or something, so apologies if that's the case, but I am stumped a good'un.

Comment: is it possible that `usage` doesn't always return the same value? Maybe call it once and use that value in the logging and the if statement, rather than calling it twice.

Comment: Your `if` statement is fine, the values must not be what you think they are.

Comment: It's very unlikely since it is idempotent, but since I'm at the end of my tether, I'll give it a whirl :D

Comment: In your test you use `usage` but in your code `usage(user)`. That's just for demonstration purposes? or does `usage(user)` return something different

Comment: I'm assuming the values are exactly what I expect, and so it was quicker to just use a variable instead of pull all the values together in a django shell.

Comment: In your program, can you do `print map(type, (old_size, new_size, date_exceeded, usage(user)))` (just to make sure it's definitely not a type error somewhere)

Comment: @JonClements you win! `[<type 'long'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'datetime.datetime'>, <type 'int'>]`. Make an answer and I'll points you :)

Comment: Yes @TheMerovingian I got that now :). Now to track down how this happened

Comment: Ahh ok, I was converting from GB to bytes using a string formatting to remove the decimal places. Changing that to `long()` fixed it. Thanks all :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're trying to compare different types (which are allowed - but the meaning is somewhat pointless)...

If you try:

```
print map(type, (old_size, new_size, date_exceeded, usage(user)))
```

And then go from there...